# Django - how to perform arithmetic operations in a class in models.py

Tags: django, django-models

I want to calculate salary of employees through my equation

```
total_salary = (time_out - time_in )*base_salary + (time_out - 8PM)*base_salary*0.20
```

Here is my model:

```
class salary(models.Model):
    empname = models.ForeignKey('employee1',default='0',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    base_salary = models.IntegerField(default='0', help_text="Base Salary")
    time_in = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    time_out = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    total_salary = models.CharField(max_length=20,default='0',blank=True,editable=False)

    def default_over_time():
        now = datetime.now()
        start = now.replace(hour=8, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
        return start if start > now else start + timedelta(days=1)

    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.total_salary=(self.time_out - self.time_in)
        self.total_salary=(self.time_out - self.time_in )*  self.base_salary + (self.time_out - self.default_over_time) * self.base_salary*0.20
        self.total_salary=str(self.total_salary)
        super(salary,self).save(*args,**kwargs)
```

Comment: what do you mean by class? Do you want that in views? or you want it in models itself? also please arrange your code properly. If you are looking dor custom model fields then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28529179/django-creating-a-custom-model-field

Comment: @py-D I Have Arranged my code now. I want to calculate salary using my equation --> total_salary=(time_out - time_in )* base_salary + (time_out - 8PM) * base_salary*0.20

Comment: what do you mean by class? Do you want that in views? or you want it in models itself?

Comment: @py-D models itself

Comment: okz, it means you have to override django model save method. So refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269605/django-override-save-for-model

Comment: @py-D but my question is how to calculate salary my equation is not working

Comment: ok... so please check your code by removing editable clause of total_salary field. And I will suggest that choose a variable in save method for calculation  of salary rather than everytime assigning same value to filed.

Comment: @py-D Exception Value: 
unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.datetime' and 'method'.This error came when i tried to save the information

Comment: Check out my answer

Comment: @Ralf can you help me with this too Please   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49909926/how-to-import-data-from-csv-file-to-django-sqlite-using-import-py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few observations I would like to make to your code before answering:

1. do not use `default='0'` argument with your `ForeignKey`.
2. `base_salary` is a `IntegerField` so you should not use a string as the default value.
3. Is your `base_salary` for each hour? Or per day? Or month?
4. I suggest using [Djangos `timezone`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/timezones/) instead of pythons `datetime` library.
5. Are you sure you want a `CharField` for your `total_salary`?

---

Here is my suggestion as to how you could calculate your salary:

```
from datetime import timedelta
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone as tz

class Salary(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey('Employee', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    base_salary = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    time_in = models.DateTimeField(default=tz.now, null=True, blank=True)
    time_out = models.DateTimeField(default=tz.now, null=True, blank=True)
    total_salary = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='0')

    def calculate_salary(self):
        worked_hours = (self.time_out - self.time_in).total_seconds() / 60 / 60
        overtime_hours = 0

        # make sure you use timezone aware objects
        # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/timezones/#naive-and-aware-datetime-objects
        same_day_8pm = self.time_out.replace(hour=20, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
        if self.time_out > same_day_8pm:
            overtime_hours = (self.time_out - same_day_8pm).total_seconds() / 60 / 60

        salary_1 = worked_hours * self.base_salary
        salary_2 = overtime_hours * self.base_salary * 0.2
        total_salary = salary_1 + salary_2

        # careful: this will be a 'float', not an 'int'
        # with round() using 0 decimal digits you get an 'int'
        # total_salary = round(total_salary, 0)

        return total_salary

    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        # are you really sure that you want to save a string ???
        self.total_salary = str(self.calculate_salary())
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

---

EDIT after @Ashish made the following comment:

> my requirements are changed & i Have to change the DateTimeField To TimeField of timein & timeout........But when i make the changes in your given answer i face an error (Exception Value: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.time' )

I advise against using `TimeField` for this case because it makes the calculation a bit more complicated.
And it doesn't hurt to have the extra date info stored with the `DateTimeField` (for example, when `time_in` and `time_out` are on different days, maybe just after midnight).

But if your hands are tied on this matter, then lets get you sorted out:

You are seeing the error because [djangos `TimeField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#timefield) uses [pythons `datetime.time`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#time-objects), which does not support the `-` operation.
See also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096953/how-to-calculate-the-time-interval-between-two-time-strings/3096984) for a similar task.

You could overcome this by converting to `datetime.datetime` objects like this:

```
import datetime as dt
new_time_in = dt.datetime(
    year=2000, month=1, day=1,  # choose an arbitrary date
    hour=time_in.hour,
    minute=time_in.minute,
    second=time_in.second,
    tzinfo=time_in.tzinfo)
new_time_out = dt.datetime(
    year=2000, month=1, day=1,  # use the same date as before
    hour=time_out.hour,
    minute=time_out.minute,
    second=time_out.second,
    tzinfo=time_out.tzinfo)
```

Comment: Thank You So much @Ralf This was the perfect solution i was looking for since so many days Thanks alot

Comment: can you help me with this too..  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49909926/how-to-import-data-from-csv-file-to-django-sqlite-using-import-py

Comment: Sir need one more help

Comment: my requirements are changed & i Have to change the DateTimeField To TimeField of timein & timeout........But when i make the changes in your given answer i face an error (Exception Value: 
unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.time' )

Comment: I added some thoughts to the end of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you are going ot calculate salary from base salary but as far as your formula is concern  `self.time_out - self.time_in` it will give you a datetime object.

So you have to convert it to seconds or hours. like

```
a1 = self.time_out - self.time_in
total_sec = a1.total_seconds()
```

same for `self.time_out - self.default_over_time`

**EDIT:**

Four your case as per your comment you have to convert timedifference to hours and then you have to use the same in your formula for the same you can use `divmod`.
ex.

```
a1 = self.time_out - self.time_in
total_sec = a1.total_seconds()
minutes,second = divmod(total_sec,60)
hours,minutes = divmod(minutes,60)
```

from above you will get total hours and can use the same in you formula.

**EDIT 2:**

convert time to datetime and then go for difference. ex.

```
datetime.strptime(self.time_out.strftime('%H:%I'),'%H:%I') - datetime.strptime(self.time_in.strftime('%H:%I'),'%H:%I')
```

Comment: Thank you But i need your help for the answer provided by Ralf below my question......my requirements are changed & i Have to change the DateTimeField To TimeField of timein & timeout........But when i make the changes in your given answer i face an error (Exception Value: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.time' )

Comment: convert time to datetime and then go for difference. ex. datetime.strptime(self.time_out.strftime('%H:%I'),'%H:%I') - datetime.strptime(self.time_in.strftime('%H:%I'),'%H:%I') @Ashish