# how to import data from .csv file to django sqlite using import.py

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

i want to retrieve data from csv file but my hardware(RFID) output gives me two different entries of same employee for timein & timeout
[WorkNames.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAYnQ.png)

In this there are double entries i want only one row for one employee in models.py Employee class

**so please help in my METHOD1 by suggesting some code which can combine 2rows into one while transfering data into sqlite**

*OR*

**by helping in METHOD2 by suggesting some code to import data from output.csv**

METHOD 1: I used **import.py** to import data. Data is imported to sqlite but double entries

```
import os
import sys
import csv
from datetime import datetime

project_dir='catalog'
sys.path.append(project_dir)

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE']='locallibrary.settings'
import django
django.setup()

from catalog.models import employee1
data=csv.reader(open('locallibrary/WorkNames.csv'),delimiter=',')
i=1
from datetime import datetime

for row in data:
    if row[0]== '':
        break
    else:


    Employee1=employee1()
    Employee1.Date=row[0]
    Employee1.Name=row[1]
    Employee1.Number=row[2]
    if row[3] =="" or row[3]=='Time IN':
        Employee1.Time_IN='00:00:00 AM'
    else:
        Employee1.Time_IN=str(row[3])

    if row[4] =="" or row[4]=='Time OUT':

        Employee1.Time_OUT='00:00:00 AM'
    else:
        Employee1.Time_OUT=str(row[4])

    Employee1.save()
```

**METHOD 2:but to get a timein timeout in row I generated a new file **[output.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXfsx.png)

the file is genrated properly but data is not importing from csv to sqlite

```
import os
import sys
import csv
from datetime import datetime

project_dir='catalog'
sys.path.append(project_dir)

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE']='locallibrary.settings'
import django

django.setup()

from catalog.models import employee1
data=csv.reader(open('locallibrary/WorkNames.csv'),delimiter=',')

from datetime import datetime
lines=list(data)

r=5
c=5

for i in range(r):
    for j in range(1,5):
        if lines[0][j]=="":
            break

        if lines[i][2] == lines[j][2]:
            lines[j][3]=lines[i][3]

r=5
c=5

for i in range(r):
    for j in range(1,5):
        if lines[i][3]!="" and lines[i][4]=="":
            lines[i][3]='00:00:00 AM'
            lines[i][4]='00:00:00 AM'
            break


writer = csv.writer(open('locallibrary/output.csv', 'w'))
for r in lines:
    writer.writerow(r)

open('locallibrary/output.csv').close()


data1=csv.reader(open('locallibrary/WorkNames.csv'),delimiter=',')
i=1

for row in data:
    if row['Date']=='':
            break
    else:
        Employee1=employee1()
        Employee1.Date=row['Date']
        Employee1.Name=row['Name']
        Employee1.Number=row['Number']
        Employee1.Time_IN=row['Time IN']
        Employee1.Time_OUT=row['Time OUT']
        Employee1.save()
```

**so please help in my METHOD1 by suggesting some code which can combine 2rows into one while transfering data into sqlite**

*OR*

**by helping in METHOD2 by suggesting some code to import data from output.csv**

Comment: @Ralf can you help me with this too.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion for your method 1

If there aren't to many rows in your CSV file (maybe less than 10.000), then you could use a python `dict` to group by employee number and date.

I modified a little part of your code:

```
... some code ...

record_dict = {}

for row in data:
    if row[0] == '':
        break

    record_date = row[0]
    emp_number = row[2]
    key = (emp_number, record_date)

    if key not in record_dict:
        record_dict[key] = employee1()
        record_dict[key].Date = row[0]
        record_dict[key].Name = row[1]
        record_dict[key].Number = row[2]
        record_dict[key].Time_IN = None
        record_dict[key].Time_OUT = None

    if row[3] not in ('', 'Time IN'):
        record_dict[key].Time_IN = row[3]
    if row[4] not in ('', 'Time OUT'):
        record_dict[key].Time_OUT = row[4]

for emp in record_dict.values():
    emp.save()
```

By the way: you should read [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), which is the python coding style guide showing the preferred way to write python code.

Comment: the code you provided does the same work which my method 1 did timein & timeout are in seprate row

Comment: when I show card to RFID sensor in excel sheet timein is recorded to system time & timeout is left blank. When i again show the card to sensor new entry is made for the same card where timein is blank and timeout is recorded

Comment: while im importing csv file data to sqlite i want single entry in my database not 1 entry for timein & another entry for timeout

Comment: My code iterates over all the rows from the CSV and checks if a record for that `emp_number` and date already exists in `record_dict`; if it exists (meaning there was already a row with that date and employee) my code adds the new info (time out or time in) to that same record.